# How long does it take to read a sector?

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems

Given disk rotation speed : 7200 RPM
sectors : 500 of 512 bytes around the outer cylinder.

How long does it take to read a sector ?

Average rotational delay - (0.5 * 60 * 1000)/ 7200 = 4.166ms So disk rotate every 4.166 ms so each sector will take 4.166/500 = 0.008332 ms

So to read a single sector it's going to take 4.166 + 0.008332 = 4.1749 ms.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 1/ Is this homework? 2/ What is the actual problem are you facing? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. "

Comment: Here is a [very similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/841679/average-time-to-read-a-single-sector-disk) the only difference seems to be the disk RPM.

Comment: In case you have empty queue (no other read/write is pending operation) and the head is directly on the sector, you want to read...

Comment: "500 of 512 bytes ...."  A disk has millions of sectors each cylinder has to many more than 1 sector per cylinder.